# Error when executing data flow job with new service account : Current user cannot act as service account pa-tf-multi@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

```
Caused by: 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 
403 Forbidden
POST https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev/locations/europe-west1/jobs
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
"domain" : "global",
"message" : "(b04b0291fadae2a5): Current user cannot act as service account pa-tf-multi@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Causes: (b04b0291fadae750): Current user cannot act as service account pa-tf-multi@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
"reason" : "forbidden"
} ],
"message" : "(b04b0291fadae2a5): Current user cannot act as service account pa-tf-multi@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Causes: (b04b0291fadae750): Current user cannot act as service account pa-tf-multi@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com.",
"status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:428)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
```

Comment: I got the error even though the account executing the command (personal user) was the owner and had the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission.

What solved the problem for me was setting the project `gcloud config set project xyz` in which the the Service-Account was created.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run any Google Cloud Platform process using your own service account, the user starting the process needs to be a **Service Account User** for that service account.

Granting the Service Account User role to a user for a service account can be accomplished by either:

1. Granting the user the Service Account User role at the GCP project level.  This can be done through the [IAM settings found in the GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).
2. Granting the user the Service Account User role at the individual service account level.  This too can be done through the console by managing the permissions on the [service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).

Further information can be found in the [Google Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role):

> You can grant the Service Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) at the project level for all service accounts in the project, or at the service account level.
>
> - Granting the Service Account User role to a user for a project gives the user access to all service accounts in the project, including service accounts that might be created in the future.
> - Granting the Service Account User role to a user for a specific service account gives a user access to only that service account.

Comment: Hi @Brent Worden , Thanks for the response, Devops engineer has provided the permssions however im still facing the access issue.

Comment: User : pa-tf is provided Service Account User role at the individual service account level.

Comment: Resource :- //iam.googleapis.com/projects/skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev/serviceAccounts/pa-tf-multi@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
Principal : - pa-tf-dev@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com
ROle grant :- Service Account User  Permission Grant :- iam.serviceAccounts.actAs Inheritance:- //iam.googleapis.com/projects/skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev/serviceAccounts/pa-tf-multi@skyuk-uk-pa-tf-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com